# Remove duplicated element into a file

Tags: bash, awk

Hel lo, I have a huge file, here is a head  :

```
>Sequence1:p
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence2:ok
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTGGAGAGA
>Sequence:YU
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTAGAG
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTGGAGAGA
....
```

As you can see the file is composed of several sequences :

they always begin with a its name : `>name` 
and is followed by letters.

Here I would like to remove duplicated sequences by there names

In the exemple :

`>Sequence:LJ` and `>Sequence3/lo` are present twice.

Then I would like to only keep on and get a new file without dulicated sequences :

```
>Sequence1:p
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence2:ok
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTGGAGAGA
>Sequence:YU
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTAGAG
```

does someone have an idea with bash code or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` should be be very helpful in here, could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk 'match($0,/^>.*/){val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);if(!array[val]++){found=1} else{found=""}} found'  Input_file
```

Or adding a non-one liner form of solution here:

```
awk '
match($0,/^>.*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  if(!array[val]++){
    found=1
  }
  else{
    found=""
  }
}
found
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
>Sequence1:p
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence2:ok
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:YU
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTAGAG
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '/>/{c=a[$1]++}!c' file
>Sequence1:p
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence2:ok
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:YU
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTAGAG
```

Answer (score 3):

Another awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}NR>1&&!a[$1]++{printf ">%s",$0}' file
```

Output:

```
>Sequence1:p
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence2:ok
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence3/lo
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:LJ
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
>Sequence:YU
AAAAAAACCCCCTTTGGGGAGAGAGAGGAACACAGATAATGATAAGTAGATATGATTATAGTAG
CAGAYAGTATGAGTAGTAAGTGAATTAGTAGTAGTAGATGATGA
ATTAGAG
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to process FASTA files with awk, is to build up a variable called `name` and a variable called `seq`. Every time you read a full sequence, you can process it. Remark that, for the best way of processing, the sequence, should be stored as a continues string, and not contain any newlines or whitespaces due. A generic awk for processing fasta, looks like this:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { process_sequence_here }
     /^>/{name=$0; seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence_here }' file.fasta
```

You can make this a bit easier by introducing a couple of functions:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { process_sequence(name_seq) }
     /^>/{name=substr($0,2); seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence(name,seq) }

     BEGIN{seq_ere=sprintf("%80s","");gsub(" ",".",seq_ere) }
     function print_sequence(name,seq) {
         gsub(seq_ere,"&" ORS, seq); print ">" name ORS seq
     }
     function process_sequence(name,seq) { ... }
    ' file.fasta
```

In case of the OP, the above would read:

```
awk '/^>/ && seq { process_sequence(name_seq) }
     /^>/{name=substr($0,2); seq=""; next}
     {seq = seq $0 }
     END { process_sequence(name,seq) }

     BEGIN{seq_ere=sprintf("%80s","");gsub(" ",".",seq_ere) }
     function print_sequence(name,seq) {
         gsub(seq_ere,"&" ORS, seq); print ">" name ORS seq
     }
     function process_sequence(name,seq) {
         if ! (name in a) print_sequence (name,seq)
         a[name]
     }
    ' file.fasta
```

When you process fasta-files with awk, you can always concider to use [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk). It has all the bells-and-whistles from POSIX awk, but is augmented to easily process FASTA files:

> **Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
>   by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
>   (Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
>   . I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).